# Trouble with getting DateAdd to correctly formulate

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm having two issues that I cannot seem to get unkinked.  I run reports from a master sheet based off of a template and each finished sheet will have varying numbers of rows.  What each finished sheet has in common are two columns(one for a begin date [Column F] and on for an expiration date[Column H]).  For each row with a date in Column F I need to add 60 days to the date and put that date in Column H. I have tried working with variations of:

```
Dim cell As Range 
For Each cell In Selection  
cell.Value = cell.Value + 60
Next cell
```

I have tried this also with combinations of different while statements that I use for other things where I am putting values in one column based off of another, but I can't get them to work either.

Some of the problems I am having are: first, when I do manage to get it to enter a date in Column H it always enters 2/29/1900.  It doesn't matter if there's a date in Column F or not, or what that date is.  Second, when I try to set a range for the selection (this is when I try to combine with "While" statements) it pastes a date number in the entire range instead of only the cells with a date in Column F.

How can I get the macro to only add a date in Column H if there is a date in Column F, and how can I get the darn thing to add 60 days correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

Dim c As Range, val

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E100")
        val = c.Value
        If Len(val) > 0 And IsDate(val) Then
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = val + 60
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: You sneaky bugger! I almost didn't see that your example had Column E as a reference instead of F.  That does seem to do the trick.  Thank you sir.

Comment: @Jon: your question seems to bounce between E anf F - wasn't sure which one you really meant...